# How to create text wrap img layout like css in flutter。

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

i want let the text wrap the hot tag，how i am to do？

- type 1: not align
- type 2: not in one line
- type 3:  very close but did not set padding and margin , i didn't find some lineHeight property etc。

```dart
 var Infomation = Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                color: Colors.redAccent,
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 5),
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
                child: Text("hot", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20)),
              ),
              Expanded(child: Text("Ecuador imports an immortal red rose and two-color immortal embroidery ball all its life", textScaleFactor: 1.5, maxLines: 2, overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis))
            ],
          ),
          Wrap(
            direction: Axis.horizontal,
            crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                color: Colors.redAccent,
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 5),
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
                child: Text("hot", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20)),
              ),
              Text("Ecuador imports an immortal red rose and two-color immortal embroidery ball all its life", textScaleFactor: 1.5, maxLines: 2, overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis)
            ],
          ),
          RichText(
              textAlign: TextAlign.start,
              text: TextSpan(
                  text: "hot",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, backgroundColor: Colors.red, fontSize: 24) ,
                  children: [
                    TextSpan(
                        text: "Ecuador imports an immortal red rose and two-color immortal embroidery ball all its life",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 18,
                      )
                    )
                  ]
              ),
              maxLines: 2
          )
        ],
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

the screenshot is in here https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MpHV.png

I don't seem to have enough prestige to use pictures.